# Comments: "You are not authorized to post comments."

Tags: users, comments

I'm using Drupal 7.
I'm trying to add comments to a node but I get this error back:"You are not authorized to post comments".
I can't find in the code which variables are being checked to don't allow me to post a comment. 
Can someone tell me where to look in the code?
Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

Go to: admin/people/permissions

Check de permission:

- Post comments

Click button "save permission".

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking for the [`comment_access()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21comment%21comment.module/function/comment_access/7.x) function.

> Determines whether the current user has access to a particular comment.

There's not much to it:

```
function comment_access($op, $comment) {
  global $user;

  if ($op == 'edit') {
    return ($user->uid && $user->uid == $comment->uid && $comment->status == COMMENT_PUBLISHED && user_access('edit own comments')) || user_access('administer comments');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have not already checked, go to People>Permissions>Comments.

Comment: It is checked, thanks. The thing is that I want to know where in the code the comments system checks the permissions variables: user->id, global['user'], etc...